# Use xcolor for colored tables in a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, lyx, color

How can I use a table with alternately colored rows like this in a `beamer` slide?  There seems to be a conflict with `beamer` and `xcolor`.  I am using LyX too, bonus marks for something that works well in LyX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{tableShade}{white}
\rowcolors[]{2}{blue!20}{blue!10}
\begin{tabular}{ r p{4cm} l}\hline
\textbf{col1} &\textbf{col2} &\textbf{col3}\\\hline
& & \\
& & \\
& & \\
& & \\
& & \\
& & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that that `beamer` already loads `xcolor`, but without the table option. LaTeX generates an error if a package is loaded twice with different options. So you have to get the first instance to be loaded with the `table` option.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's easy:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
```

or

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
```

You can also use:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
```

Comment: I think the first option works in Lyx.  You need to go to the toolbar and select Document -> Settings -> select "Document Class" from the sidebar -> Go to the "Custom" box in the "Class Options" section -> enter "table"

Comment: I face the same problem, in LyX, when both LyX' `Track Changes` function is active as well as the `Show changes in output` option. Entering the `table` or `xcolor=table` option does not help. Neither does the command `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}`. Any ideas?

Comment: It works using `table` as a document class option and, of course, erasing (if any) the `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` entry from the Preamble. It does not work using `xcolor=table`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also pass it as follows:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the option xcolor=table of beamer until now, and suddenly it stopped working.

When I code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{red}{green}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1&2\\
3&4\\
5&6\\
7&8
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I get the error "\rowcolors undefined".

On the other hand, if I code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{red}{green}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1&2\\
3&4\\
5&6\\
7&8
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

it works.

I wonder why doing it the first way no longer works.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/226450)