# How to display image in jpg format in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, graphics, scale

I'm using Beamer as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg,.pdf,.mps} % Para versão PDF
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{Curso de Javascript}
% \subtitle{Subtítulo}
%\date{\today}
\date{29/04/2019}
\author{Prof. Dr. Ricardo Ramos de Oliveira}
\institute{IFSULDEMINAS - Programação Web I - 1ª/2019}
% \titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.pdf}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Introdução}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Javascript - Introdução}

História do Javascript

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Javascript - Introdução}

    \textbf{Javascript - JS}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Linguagem de Programação do Navaegador (Javascript - Abreviação JS);
        \item É uma linguagem interpretada e Orientada a Objetos (OO);
        \item Interpretada pelo Navegador;
        \item Utilizada tanto do lado cliente quanto do servidor (NodeJS);
        \item Javascript $\neq$ Java;
        \item Javascript para Sistemas Embarcados \footnote{\textbf{Biblioteca johnny-five: }http://johnny-five.io/}.
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Javascript - Introdução}

\textbf{Engine Javascript - Interpretador JS}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{JavascriptEngine.jpg}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Javascript - Introdução}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{firefox.png}
\caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, my code displays only the second figure in `.png` format and I do not know why Beamer is not displaying the image in`.jpg` format. Could anyone tell me what I did wrong?

In addition, the following message appears in Overleaf:

```
 Dimension too large.

<to be read again> 
                   b
l.7 ...degraphics[scale=0.4]{JavascriptEngine.jpg}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

My Figure `JavascriptEngine.jpg`

[image]

Comment: Scale is relative so if  the jpg is reporting it is over 100 foot wide then scale=0.4= over 20 feet That is unlikely to be the real problem and scaling jpeg down to a page size pdf may simply postpone inherent issues, **Best to re-save copy of Jpg as a png** which should have a default scale of 96 dpi

Comment: Hello, KJO, thank you very much for your help! I tested your alternative too, but it did not work for my figure and still gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your low res png
[image]

or down load this higher quality one as PNG
[image]
or clip one from the image below
which should work as it gets saved here as 96dpi by most browsers

However I would try to find your source graphic and save as png since that would be crisp whereas jpg is certainly NOT suited to graphic images (photos only)

You could always build direct in Latex see the tabular section here where I compare it with PNG and JPG

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \RequirePackage{fontspec} uncomment for use with xelatex
% \setmainfont{Arial} uncomment for use with arial font on windows
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \cellcolor{green!75}Browser & \cellcolor{green!75}Engine Name    \\ \hline
        Chrome  & V8             \\ \hline
        Firefox & SpiderMonkey   \\ \hline
        Edge    & Chakra         \\ \hline
        Safari  & JavaScriptCore \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
Vector format (scalable by choice of fontsize)
\end{table}
\par\noindent
\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{browsers.png}\newline
32bit 1169x616 pixels @ 96dpi = (81,920 bytes) = SMALLER and Better
\newline\par\noindent
\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{browsers.jpg}\newline
24bit 1169x616 pixels @ 96dpi = (151,552 bytes)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @KJO, thank you very much for all your help! However, I'm using beamer and in beamer we have to use the following line: `\documentclass[table, 15pt]{beamer}`. According to the following link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/use-xcolor-for-colored-tables-in-a-beamer-slide Have a great week, my friend!

Answer (score 3):

- Just use a dimension, that is relative to the page (or an absolute dimension like 20mm).
- The resolution in dpi is not important in my opinion (referring to user @KJO comment) - important is the absolute number in pixels (Full HD has a width of 1920 pixels).

`\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{JavascriptEngine.jpg}`

Comment: Hello, Dr. Manuel Kuehner, thank you very much for your help, but I did the test with your answer and it did not work. My figure has a low resolution, I even edited my question with the image.

Comment: @ricardoramos If the image quality is not good, then it has nothing to do with Latex.

Comment: Hello @Dr. Manuel Kuehner, thank you too for all your help! Really the image quality is not good and I ended up using the latex table of KJO. Have a great week, my friend!

Answer (score 1):

best way is to convert jpg to eps e.g. `jpg2eps` and use `\usepackage{graphicx}`

and

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{com_2020_2.eps}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Why convert to eps? Pdflatex works well with jpg files and eps images would be converted nevertheless.